# Dynamically adding products to store by angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a store webpage and I want to add product blocks when user scrolls down (by infinite scrolling).

Which method should I use to fetch data from server and add it to the dom?

I saw this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mort3za/CMqMe/) for implementing infinite scrolling in angularjs (it runs a loadMore() function when user arrives to end of page), as mentioned above, blocks are store's product and every item should have different scope.

The problem is that I don't know how to structure data in a scope and adding more items to it by ajax requests in the `loadMore()` function.

My products template:

```
<section class="more-apps">
    <h1>More recommendations</h1>
    <div class="loadmore-these">
        <!-- ajax requests will load more instances of these three templates -->
        <div data-ng-include data-src="'products-template-1.html'"></div>
        <div data-ng-include data-src="'products-template-2.html'"></div>
        <div data-ng-include data-src="'products-template-3.html'"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and every sub-template file is like this with some simple differences:

```
<section data-ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]">
<h1 data-ng-bind-html="title"></h1>
    <div data-ng-bind-html="about"></div>
</section>
```

Every product has different `title` and `about` variables in (it's own?) scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you go through the angularjs official tutorial (basically it's about what you want to do, list products from a webstore) , and specifically the step about $http and services :

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

If you structure your service to download a range of products according to how much the user scrolled (as in the example you linked to) you should be set.